# Android how to save checkbox state if exit app in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have RecycerView Adapter and checkbox in onBindViewHolder function. I need to save state "checked" or "unchecked" of checkbox if i exit app. I have tried SharedPreferences, but i cant use it in Adapter, how can i do this?

Code Adapter:

```
private lateinit var databaseReferenceFavorite: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var id: String

inner class ViewHolder(val binding: CarsListBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(CarsListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    with(holder) {
        with(carsList[position]) {
            Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(image).into(binding.ivCar)
            binding.tvCar.text = this.name

            binding.cbFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener { checkBox, isChecked ->
                if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                    val image: String = this.image
                    val name: String = this.name

                    databaseReferenceFavorite = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                        .child("Cars")
                        .child("Favorite Item")

                    val favorite = Favorite(name, image)

                    id = databaseReferenceFavorite.push().key.toString()
                    databaseReferenceFavorite.child(id).setValue(favorite)

                    Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Item added to favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    databaseReferenceFavorite = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cars").child("Favorite Item").child(id)
                    databaseReferenceFavorite.removeValue()

                    Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Item removed from favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return carsList.size
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo oh i forgot to add a line of code that doesn't work :( ok, i have tried use `prefs: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences()` in `onBindViewHolder` but i got an error `Unresolved reference: getSharedPreferences`

Comment: So that's not a Firebase-related question, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo maybe i can solve this problem using firebase? Why not, but i don't know how i can do this

Comment: This line `databaseReferenceFavorite.child(id).setValue(favorite)` , does the value updated on the Firebase Database?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, move your firebase database operations from adapter to Activity/Fragment and replace with interface:

```
    private AdapterListener mListener;

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: CarsListBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(CarsListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        with(holder) {
            with(carsList[position]) {
                Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(image).into(binding.ivCar)
                binding.tvCar.text = this.name
    
                binding.cbFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener { checkBox, isChecked ->
                    if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                        mListener.onFavoriteClick(carsList[position], true);
                    }else{
                        mListener.onFavoriteClick(carsList[position], false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return carsList.size
    }

public void setListener(AdapterListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface AdapterListener {

        void onItemClick(Car item);
        void onFavoriteClick(Car item, boolean isFavorite);
    }
```

In Activity or Fragment:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
        implements YourAdapter.AdapterListener {
        ...
        mCarRef = mDatabase.child("Cars"));

@Override
    public void onFavoriteClick(Car item, boolean isFavorite) {
      checkFavorite(mCarRef);
    }

private void checkFavorite(Car item, DatabaseReference reference){

        reference.child(item.getId())
                .child("Favorites")
                .child("userId").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String favorite = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                if (favorite != null){
                    removeFavoriteFromCars("userId");
                   
                }else {
                    addFavoriteToCars("userId");
            
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

private void addFavoriteToCars(String userId) {

        mCarRef.child("Favorites").child(userId).setValue(userId)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private void removeFavoriteFromCars(String userId) {

        mCarRef.child("Favorites").child(userId).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
          
            }
        });
    }
```